# Is it safe to only use the Public firewall on a Windows 7 computer with SQL server which has no connectivity to the Internet?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, sql-server, windows-firewall

One of our Windows 7 computer with SQL server installed on it only uses the Public firewall because other computers on the network cannot access the SQL server if the private firewall is turned on. Is it safe to leave the Private firewall disabled on a computer which is not exposed to the Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended practice is to only open up the firewall to the services required. By disabling the firewall you've opened up every service on the Windows 7 computer to the local network. Enable the firewall and allow the SQL Server through the firewall.

It's straightforward to allow SQL Server through the Windows Firewall, I answered how to do this in the following [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1303512/unblocking-windows-10-defender-firewall-for-ms-sql-server-2014/1303955#1303955).

Comment: Great answer! I took a look at your other answer, and it's working. I just have a question regarding that other answer, which I'm not sure I should address here or as a comment there. Microsoft states [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15#ports-used-by-) that it is better to set a static port because with dynamic ports it is difficult to audit which ports are open and an update can change the executable paths you mention in your article. Do you agree?

Comment: Also, if I disable SQL Browser because I want to use a static port, are you sure it's not going to break something when clients try to connect to the server. Essentially, my question is: is SQL Browser only needed when you use dynamic ports and is it safe to disable it when you don't use them?

Comment: Microsoft's recommendations on ports makes theoretical sense, but I have never seen Microsoft change the path to an executable in the last 10 years due to an update. If you have a separate firewall other than the windows one, then it would make sense to use a fixed port.

Comment: Regarding the SQL browser, it will work fine without the browser running if a static port is setup. The only other thing I know the SQL browser does is to allow clients to search the network for SQL servers, making it easier for clients to connect. Without the browser you have to know the exact server name and port.

Comment: I agree with you regarding Microsoft not changing paths often, I didn't know that but it makes sense. What about their other argument, that is the difficulty to audit open ports if they're dynamic? Do SQL Server and Browser ports change often when they're dynamic? What are the chances that they will change if the computer is restarted? And if the computer is always on, will they ever change?

Comment: I'd expect dynamic ports to be picked when the SQL Server is started up and therefore to change on a restart. I don't think it is practical to say that a Windows PC will never be restarted.  If you are using an external firewall you will have to specify the port to use, so your only choice really is to make the SQL Server use a fixed port.